# Should the system be in domain to login as active directory user?

Tags: dns, active-directory, gpo

I want to prevent my system to get GPO's of domain. Thus thinking if i can still login as one of the domain user without putting the system in domain.

If not is there a way to atleast prevent the domain policy to be applied to local system.

Comment: This seems a more suitable question for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about the first part of the question as im also trying find the answer for the same question but however the second part is possible by a domain controller.

Please find the Microsoft link to implement the same.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816100